# Why can't we use a slip ring instead of a split ring in a dc motor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity, conductors

I've been taught that in a dc electric motor a split ring is used to connect the two ends of the rotating coil to two carbon brushes so that

1. The wire does not get twisted and
2. The current passing through the coil gets reversed.

I've wondered what would happen if the split ring was replaced by a slip ring and as per some sites on the internet, a motor with a slip ring would not work because

1. The current won't get reversed in the coil, in consequence to which the coil won't be able to rotate completely and will only oscillate up and down.
2. Using a slip ring will cause a short circuit.

I fail to understand why using a slip ring will stop the current from getting reversed. [image]
As per my understanding, In diagram 1, as soon as the switch is turned on and current starts to flow, the arms AB and CD rotate and interchange positions (diagram 2) . Then they again rotate and interchange positions (back to diagram 1). Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a single slipring it will produce a short circuit.  No current will flow though the armature it will all just flow from one brush into one side of the slipring directly to the other side of the slip ring and out the other brush.

You could get your motor to work using two slip rings, as is done in some generators, and supplying it with an alternating current.  This is not the way most AC motors work though.

Answer (score 0):

A slip ring is used in an AC generator or motor to transfer power or signals from a fixed part to a rotating part. In a DC motor, the commutator (split ring) is used to switch the current direction in the armature and to maintain continuous rotation in the same direction. The commutator allows the current to flow in the same direction as the magnetic field generated by the stator. If a slip ring was used instead of a commutator, the current direction in the armature would change continuously and the motor would not rotate continuously in one direction. Therefore, a commutator (split ring) is essential for the proper functioning of a DC motor.

Because you have to change a lot of things of slip ring, if you want to use it and customize it well, you can choose some brand manufacturers, such as Orbinexus, Moog etc.